# Aufenthaltserlaubnis expiry, waiting for passport renewal

Tags: germany, residence-cards, russian-citizens

My wife is a Russian citizen, living in Germany with a valid Aufenthaltstitel since early 2019.

Her Russian passport expires soon, and her Aufenthaltstitel card expires on the same date (just the current card, her actual residence is valid beyond that date: under “Anmerkungen” the card states “Titel gültig bis xx xx 2023”). She has already applied for a new passport, but not yet received it.

What does she need to do if the passport is still not ready by the time the Aufenthaltstitel card expires?

Further information that may be relevant:

- we live in Hamburg
- I am a British/German dual citizen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inform the immigration office that a new passport application has been made (with a copy of the application or the details showing when the application was made) and that it may not be issued on time before the passport expires.

Should there be any queries as to why your wife no longer has a valid passport, that query will eventuelly land at the immigration office. They will then know the reason why.

This would be a preemptive action on your wifes part, since the **residence permit** card fulfills the passport requirement when the passport issuing takes longer than expected (§48(2) AufenthG).

An **Ausweisersatz** (substitute identity document), that is **not** valid for travel, can be issued in cases where the period is longer than 3 months after the passport has expired.

It also fulfills a major condition to receive a temporary travel document, should one be required ([§5(1,2) AufenthV](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthv/__5.html), German only).

---

> [§48 - Obligations related to identification papers (AufenthG)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1004)
> ...
> (2) To meet the obligation to have and present identification papers, it is sufficient for a foreigner who neither possesses a passport or passport substitute nor can reasonably be expected to obtain one **to carry the certificate confirming a residence title** or the suspension of deportation, if this document contains the foreigner’s personal details and a photograph and is marked to indicate that it is a substitute identity document.
> (3) Foreigners who do not possess a valid passport or passport substitute **are required to cooperate in efforts to obtain the identity paper** and ...
> ...